Deadlocks in Linux system calls with multithreaded forking
Recently, I've been working on a tool which has to repeatedly launch executables and pipe large amounts of data into them and examine the result. As one aspect of this process is computationally intensive, I've also made it multithreaded using pthreads.
The software is only made to launch what I'll call "digesting" applications which consume arbitrary data from stdin until EOF, then print a simple output (like sha256sum).
I have provided the most minimal and complete example as I can below. Unfortunately it is still quite large. High-level description:

Master thread creates a pool of one or more worker threads and mutexes/conds for a barrier/"gate" and to indicate completion of a run of work. Worker threads run and hit the gate.
For each run:

Master 'opens' the gate.
Worker threads fork-exec sha256sum with stdin/stdout pipes and use a simple RNG to fill a buffer, write to the child, close the write pipe, read the result, and call wait.
Master waits for completion of all threads, performs any operations on data and the threads while they're safely blocked and prints their results.


Master signals the end of running and releases the gate, then joins threads.
Workers see end of running and exit their entry function.
Master uninitializes as appropriate.

This can be run with the thread count as the first argument. When using more than one thread, I find that the code rapidly gets stuck, with one or more worker threads stuck in calls to read(), close() or wait().
Valgrind's DRD and Helgrind tools find no issues/warnings with this code (and it works under them, somehow... - more deterministic scheduling I guess?).
A big step forward was discovering that threads share FDs created with pipe(), so it is clear that each child after its creation must close any pipes that it inherited which were not created by its parent. Otherwise, duplicate pipes will prevent EOF from being delivered as intended.
However, this isn't sufficient to make the code work.
Why/how is there a race condition in this code?
I understand that there are easier ways to achieve the intended result, like using a library instead of using fork-exec of programs. But I wish to identify exactly why this isn't working as a learning experience. It has been very interesting already, but it's not quite there yet.
Code:
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MIN(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (b) : (a))

#define LOG_PERROR(func, failCond) \
    do { \
        if (failCond) { \
            perror(#func); \
            abort(); \
        } \
    } \
    while (0)

#define LOG_PTHREAD(funcCall) \
    do { \
        const int res = (funcCall); \
        if (res != 0) { \
            fprintf(stderr, #funcCall " failed with ret code %" PRId32 "\n", \
                    res); \
            abort(); \
        } \
    } \
    while (0)

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t thread_count;

    pthread_mutex_t print_mutex;

    pthread_mutex_t master_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t  master_cond;

    /* Guarded by `master_mutex` */
    uint32_t threads_finished_work;

    pthread_mutex_t gate_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t  gate_cond;

    /* Guarded by `gate_mutex` */
    uint32_t gate_waiting;

    int running;
} context_t;

typedef struct
{
    context_t* ctx;
    uint32_t thread_id;
    uint32_t seed;
    char in_buf[1024];
} thread_data_t;

static void printf_guarded(context_t* ctx, const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_lock(&ctx->print_mutex));

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_unlock(&ctx->print_mutex));
}

static void do_work(thread_data_t* const td)
{
    const int32_t count = 100000000;
    const uint32_t lcg_a = UINT32_C(1664525);
    const uint32_t lcg_c = UINT32_C(1013904223);

    char out_buf[65536];
    char* args[2] = {"sha256sum", NULL};
    int pipe_in[2];
    int pipe_out[2];
    pid_t child;
    pid_t wait_res;
    ssize_t cumul_bytes = 0;
    ssize_t this_bytes;
    ssize_t res;

    assert((sizeof(count) % 4) == 0);
    assert((sizeof(out_buf) % 4) == 0);

    /*
    printf_guarded(ctx, "Thread %2" PRIu32 " | seed: %10" PRIu32 "\n",
            td->thread_id, td->seed);
    */
    LOG_PERROR(pipe, pipe(pipe_in) == -1);
    LOG_PERROR(pipe, pipe(pipe_out) == -1);

    printf_guarded(td->ctx, "Thread %2" PRIu32
            " | pipe_in = {%d, %d}, pipe_out = {%d, %d}\n",
            td->thread_id, pipe_in[0], pipe_in[1], pipe_out[0], pipe_out[1]);

    child = fork();
    LOG_PERROR(fork, child == -1);

    if (child == 0)
    {
        int i;
        struct stat statbuf;

        /* Search for and close pipes which my parent did not create. */
        for (i = 0; i < getdtablesize(); i++)
        {
            if ((i != pipe_in[0]) && (i != pipe_in[1]) &&
                (i != pipe_out[0]) && (i != pipe_out[1]))
            {
                if (fcntl(i, F_GETFD) != -1)
                {
                    if (fstat(i, &statbuf) != -1)
                    {
                        if (S_ISFIFO(statbuf.st_mode))
                        {
                            printf("Thread %2" PRIu32 " | CHILD  | "
                                    "closing unexpected pipe: fd = %d\n",
                                    td->thread_id, i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        LOG_PERROR(dup2, dup2(pipe_in[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1);
        LOG_PERROR(dup2, dup2(pipe_out[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1);
        LOG_PERROR(close, close(pipe_in[0]) == -1);
        LOG_PERROR(close, close(pipe_in[1]) == -1);
        LOG_PERROR(close, close(pipe_out[0]) == -1);
        LOG_PERROR(close, close(pipe_out[1]) == -1);

        /* Never returns */
        LOG_PERROR(execvp, execvp(args[0], args) == -1);

        perror("execvp");
        abort();
    }

    LOG_PERROR(close, close(pipe_in[0]) == -1);
    LOG_PERROR(close, close(pipe_out[1]) == -1);

    while (cumul_bytes < count)
    {
        int32_t i;
        const ssize_t to_write_bytes =
            MIN(count - cumul_bytes, (ssize_t) sizeof(out_buf));

        assert((to_write_bytes % 4) == 0);

        for (i = 0; i < (to_write_bytes / 4); i++)
        {
            const int32_t strided_idx = i * 4;
            uint32_t* casted = (uint32_t*) &out_buf[strided_idx];

            td->seed = lcg_a * td->seed + lcg_c;
            *casted = td->seed;
        }

        this_bytes = 0;

        while (this_bytes < to_write_bytes)
        {
            res = write(
                    pipe_in[1],
                    &out_buf[this_bytes],
                    to_write_bytes - this_bytes);
            LOG_PERROR(write, res == -1);
            this_bytes += res;
        }

        cumul_bytes += this_bytes;
    }

    /* Finished writing; close the write side of the in pipe. */
    LOG_PERROR(close, close(pipe_in[1]) == -1);

    this_bytes = 0;

    do
    {
        res = read(
                pipe_out[0],
                &td->in_buf[this_bytes],
                sizeof(td->in_buf) - this_bytes);
        LOG_PERROR(read, res == -1);

        if (this_bytes >= (ssize_t) sizeof(td->in_buf))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Soemthing went wrong!\n");
            abort();
        }

        this_bytes += res;
    }
    while (res > 0);

    LOG_PERROR(close, close(pipe_out[0]) == -1);
    wait_res = waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
    LOG_PERROR(waitpid, wait_res == -1);

    if (wait_res != child)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "waitpid returned unexpected result (%"
                PRId32 ")\n", wait_res);
        abort();
    }

    td->in_buf[this_bytes] = 0;
}

static void* thread_entry(void* arg)
{
    thread_data_t* const td = (thread_data_t*) arg;
    context_t* const ctx = td->ctx;

    while (1)
    {
        /* Stop all threads at gate */

        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_lock(&ctx->gate_mutex));
        ctx->gate_waiting++;
        printf_guarded(ctx, "Thread %2" PRIu32 " | gate, WAITING\n",
                td->thread_id);
        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_cond_wait(&ctx->gate_cond, &ctx->gate_mutex));
        printf_guarded(ctx, "Thread %2" PRIu32 " | gate, RELEASED\n",
                td->thread_id);
        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_unlock(&ctx->gate_mutex));

        /* All threads are now released from the gate */

        if (!ctx->running)
            break;

        do_work(td);

        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_lock(&ctx->master_mutex));

        ctx->threads_finished_work++;
        assert(ctx->threads_finished_work <= ctx->thread_count);

        /* Last thread to finish should signal the master */

        if (ctx->threads_finished_work == ctx->thread_count)
        {
            printf_guarded(ctx, "Thread %2" PRIu32
                    " | finished, signalling master\n",
                    td->thread_id);
            LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_cond_signal(&ctx->master_cond));
        }
        else
        {
            printf_guarded(ctx, "Thread %2" PRIu32 " | finished\n", td->thread_id);
        }

        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_unlock(&ctx->master_mutex));
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    context_t ctx;
    pthread_t* threads;
    thread_data_t* tds;
    uint32_t i, j;

    if (argc > 1)
        ctx.thread_count = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    else
        ctx.thread_count = 1;

    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_init(&ctx.print_mutex, NULL));

    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_init(&ctx.master_mutex, NULL));
    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_cond_init(&ctx.master_cond, NULL));

    ctx.threads_finished_work = 0;

    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_init(&ctx.gate_mutex, NULL));
    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_cond_init(&ctx.gate_cond, NULL));

    ctx.gate_waiting = 0;
    ctx.running = 1;

    threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * ctx.thread_count);
    tds = malloc(sizeof(thread_data_t) * ctx.thread_count);

    for (i = 0; i < ctx.thread_count; i++)
    {
        tds[i].ctx = &ctx;
        tds[i].thread_id = i;
        tds[i].seed = i;

        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_entry, &tds[i]));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int all_threads_at_gate = 0;

        while (!all_threads_at_gate)
        {
            LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_lock(&ctx.gate_mutex));

            assert(ctx.gate_waiting <= ctx.thread_count);

            if (ctx.gate_waiting == ctx.thread_count)
                all_threads_at_gate = 1;

            LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_unlock(&ctx.gate_mutex));

            if (!all_threads_at_gate)
                sched_yield();
        }

        printf_guarded(&ctx, "====================\nStart of run %" PRIu32
                "\nThread master has seen all threads at gate - "
                "signalling them\n", i);

        ctx.gate_waiting = 0;

        /* The threads are now good to go. */

        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_lock(&ctx.gate_mutex));
        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_cond_broadcast(&ctx.gate_cond));
        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_unlock(&ctx.gate_mutex));

        /* Wait for threads to do the work... */

        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_lock(&ctx.master_mutex));

        assert(ctx.threads_finished_work <= ctx.thread_count);

        if (ctx.threads_finished_work < ctx.thread_count)
        {
            /* Master beat the threads to this point (very likely). */

            printf_guarded(&ctx, "Thread master is waiting for signal...\n");

            LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_cond_wait(
                        &ctx.master_cond, &ctx.master_mutex));
        }
        else
        {
            printf_guarded(&ctx,
                    "Thread master didn't need to wait for signal!\n");
        }

        printf_guarded(&ctx, "Thread master is proceeding\n");
        ctx.threads_finished_work = 0;

        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_unlock(&ctx.master_mutex));

        for (j = 0; j < ctx.thread_count; j++)
        {
            printf_guarded(&ctx, "Thread %2" PRIu32 " | got output: %s",
                    tds[j].thread_id, tds[j].in_buf);
        }
    }

    ctx.running = 0;

    printf_guarded(&ctx, "Signalling threads...\n");

    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_lock(&ctx.gate_mutex));

    assert(ctx.gate_waiting == ctx.thread_count);
    ctx.running = 0;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&ctx.gate_cond);

    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_unlock(&ctx.gate_mutex));

    printf_guarded(&ctx, "Joining threads...\n");

    for (i = 0; i < ctx.thread_count; i++)
    {
        LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_join(threads[i], NULL));
        printf_guarded(&ctx, "Thread %2" PRIu32 " | final seed: %10"
                PRIu32 "\n", i, tds[i].seed);
    }

    printf_guarded(&ctx, "Now freeing...\n");

    free(tds);
    free(threads);

    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_destroy(&ctx.gate_mutex));
    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_cond_destroy(&ctx.gate_cond));

    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_destroy(&ctx.master_mutex));
    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_cond_destroy(&ctx.master_cond));

    LOG_PTHREAD(pthread_mutex_destroy(&ctx.print_mutex));

    return 0;
}


static int interrupted = 0; is wrong for a value that can be modified by a signal handler.  Per 5.1.2.3 Program execution, paragraph 5 of the (draft) C11 standard:  "When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the values of objects that are neither lock-free atomic objects nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t are unspecified,.... The value of any object modified by the handler that is neither a lock-free atomic object nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t becomes indeterminate when the handler exits"

Doing blocking writes for the whole set of data, followed by blocking reads for the whole result, is very vulnerable to deadlock. The subprocess can be blocked writing to a full pipe while the parent gets blocked for the same reason

Side note: looking at your printf_guarded(), I'm inclined to think you do not realize that (POSIX) printf() is thread safe.

After the child process dupes pipe ends onto the standard file descriptors, it has two open file descriptors for each of those pipe ends.  It should close the originals (in addition to closing the other ends of those pipes as it already does).

Have you considered finding an SHA256 library that you can use in-process, to avoid forking separate processes for that and dealing with all the resulting IPC issues?  That would probably improve performance, too.

@AndrewHenle Thanks, I didn't know that. But anyway, I realised after posting that I could have removed all that interrupt handling. The issue I have occurs regardless.

@Useless I tried to be careful by choosing a program which swallows effectively arbitrary data and only gives a result after stdin has closed. Is the deadlock you refer to a general comment, or can it occur even for this type of application? I had also been using the PRNG testing application ent, which has the same "runtime model" and has the same issue.

@JohnBollinger Thanks for your comments. Regarding printf: I thought it was thread-safe, but the two Valgrind tools (DRD and helgrind) were flagging a lot of errors within them. I'll see what I can find out about that. Regarding the dup2() pipes, thanks, I've updated the code. Sadly it doesn't fix the issue. :( I had actually considered just using a library instead, but I thought in my stubbornness that I should be able to get this working. So it's more of a challenge at this point. :)

@Doddy Read the section on F_SETPIPE_SZ  in the Linux fcntl() man page.  If you're deadlocking because processes are blocked on full pipes, making the pipe's internal buffers larger might enable things to run.

Mixing threading and multiprocessing is fraught — avoid it.  When a multi-threaded process forks, the child has only a single thread, and it can't gain access to resources locked by threads in the parent (and those resources won't be released because the thread that locked them doesn't exist in the child process).  You need to separate the forking code from the multithreading code — perhaps by having a separate process that waits for messages from the multithreaded master process and forks children in response to those requests.  Organizing the IPC is where the fun starts.

I apologise; in a rather embarrassing turn, I realise that my code was missing one line which I remembered adding but somehow managed to undo before testing and pasting the code into the question.
The close of the unexpected pipe is missing. Adding it:
        /* Search for and close pipes which my parent did not create. */
        for (i = 0; i < getdtablesize(); i++)
        {
            if ((i != pipe_in[0]) && (i != pipe_in[1]) &&
                (i != pipe_out[0]) && (i != pipe_out[1]))
            {
                if (fcntl(i, F_GETFD) != -1)
                {
                    if (fstat(i, &statbuf) != -1)
                    {
                        if (S_ISFIFO(statbuf.st_mode))
                        {
                            printf("Thread %2" PRIu32 " | CHILD  | "
                                    "closing unexpected pipe: fd = %d\n",
                                    td->thread_id, i);
                            LOG_PERROR(close, close(i) == -1); /* WAS MISSING!! */
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

This means that the code seems to work properly.
As far as I am aware, there are no other issues with this code.
With regard to mutexes: they are copied on fork but are not used by the child, so I am sure that they have no effect.
